# how to set apex heatmap border?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am referring to the *[apexcharts documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/)* to find if there is anyway to show the border of each cell in the heatmap.

So far, I have tried to add

```
grid: {
  show: true,
  borderColor: '#90A4AE',
}
```

which did not work.

fyi, this is the current state of the heatmap.

[image: partial screenshot just to show the idea, and I want to add border on each cell to make it more distinguishable]

Any suggestion will be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `stroke` color (white space between cells) like this

```
stroke: {
  colors: ["#90A4AE"],
},
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/stroke/

Comment: wos thats's perfect! I did not think about stroke would help in the first place because I do not understand the word 'stroke' here and there is no referrence/example in its document either..... thank you so much!